# How convert MongoDB query to MongoDB Kotlin Driver

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, mongodb-query

I'm trying to use the MongoDB Kotlin Driver to perform some queries on a MongoDB database, but I'm having trouble converting the queries from the MongoDB shell syntax to the Kotlin. For example, I have this query in MongoDB shell:

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      "attempts.badgeStatus": {
        $in: [
          "FILES_DOWNLOADED",
          "SAVED_TO_GCP_INCOMPLETE",
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      tmsTenantId: 1,
      gptwClientId: 1,
      attempts: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$attempts",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "$$this.badgeStatus",
              [
                "FILES_DOWNLOADED",
                "SAVED_TO_GCP_INCOMPLETE",
              ],
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
]
```

How can I write the same query using the MongoDB Kotlin Driver? I'm expecting something like this:

```
        val projection = Projections.fields(
            Projections.include((Badge::tmsTenantId).path()),
            Projections.include((Badge::gptwClientId).path()),
            Projections.include((Badge::attempts).path()),
            Projections.elemMatch(
                (Badge::attempts).path(),
                Filters.in((Badge::attempts / BadgeReplacementAttempt::badgeStatus).path(), listOf(BadgeAttemptStatus.PROCESS_SUCCEEDED))
            )
        )
```

I'm trying to use the MongoDB Kotlin Driver to perform some queries on a MongoDB database, but I'm having trouble converting the queries from the MongoDB shell syntax to the Kotlin.
How can I write the same query using the MongoDB Kotlin Driver